# A good jquery tooltip that i can have an image and text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tooltip

i am looking for a jquery tooltip plugin (with no success) that will popup an image and text in the tooltip. In the text there will be a link that they can click on so i cant just have the tooltip disappear...any ideas on a good one.. I am using this tooltip on an image map if that makes a difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

qtip is exactly what you want!

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/

I've used it with great success, and the author is very actively developing it.

It's got options for how you make them show/hide, if they stick around on mouse over,  what kind of delays you want for showing/hiding.

Comment: It looks great thanks again....the delay i need is to give the user the option to click on a link in the tooltip...

Comment: you can also make it so that the tooltips don't disapear if the user is moused over the tooltip!

Answer (score 0):

i use this script from here:
http://cssglobe.com/easiest-tooltip-and-image-preview-using-jquery/

see the Example 3: Links With URL Preview